# Is Ionic Google Analytics plugin deprecating?

Tags: phonegap-plugins, ionic4, google-analytics-sdk

I wanted to implement google Analytics for Ionic ( Android and IOS )  using the plugin https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin, which is build on Google's native Universal Analytics SDK. I learnt that google is pushing firebase instead of Google Analytics and deprecated the GA (https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9167112?hl=en)

1) Is the phonegap plugin is using the same SDK as google is deprecating ?

2) Can I use the GA Ionic plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that plugin is using the native Google Analytics SDK and yes that is the one Google has deprecated and it will cease to work in October 2019.

Try [Flurry Analytics](https://www.flurry.com/) as a free alternative.
A Cordova plugin exists ([cordova-plugin-flurryanalytics](https://github.com/Joker-1991/cordova-plugin-flurryanalytics)) but is out-of-date with respect to the latest Flurry SDK, so I have [forked it and updated it](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-flurryanalytics). To install my forked plugin:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-flurryanalytics
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Dave. Will try it.